# Truffle on Windows 10: how to unlock an account for migration to a private network

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-config

I try to migrate a smart contract to a private network via truffle on Windows 10. I specify a certain account in `truffle.js` and so far I get the following error:

```
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: authentication needed: password or unlock
```

What is the best way or the best ways to unlock the (remote) account so that the migration via `migrate --network networkName` can take place?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There might be a newer, better way, but this has always worked for me. Go to geth, and

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.personal.listAccounts[0], "<password>", 15000);
```

15000 (seconds) just tells it to keep the first account unlocked for a long time so you can work in peace.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that would be via running a local node or? I was wondering if that is possible via Truffle.

Answer (score 1):

The above did not work for me. This worked:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts( (err,res) => {first=res[0]; web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(first, "123456", 15000, (err,res)=>{console.log(err,res);} ) } );
```