# Truffle migration: Error: authentication needed: password or unlock

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-config

I'm deploying contract using Truffle and got an error `Error: authentication needed: password or unlock`. I already [checked](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11908/account-is-locked-after-running-truffle-migrate-command) [related](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12965/truffle-on-windows-10-how-to-unlock-an-account-for-migration-to-a-private-netwo) [questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10160/truffle-migrations-account-locked-error-with-network-command) and found only ugly hacks like "unlock desired account directly on node using `web3.personal.unlockAccount`". But I do not want to connect to my node each time (I have 3 test networks in my `truffle.js`) when I want to deploy new version.

My question is: is there any way to specify password in truffle infrastructure to unlock account specified in field `from` under the `network` item? `password` or `pass` does not work.

Comment: With truffle you can use a providerengine like this http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider, but with your own node.

Comment: @Ismael thank you for reply, but Infura provides very poor set of RPC calls. For instance, with Infura you cannot use even subscription because each "subscribe" call preceded with "createFilter" one that does not supported with Infura. I already tried it.

Comment: It should work the same if you use your own url to the geth instance instead of the infura one.

Comment: It checked this article twice. It looks like absolutely useless for my case. Could you please point me where exactly in your article specified account unlocking process? I see only wallet derivation, connection to remote node and... that's all.

Comment: To use a UTC file instead of the HD wallet you should do something like `const EthereumWallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');
const jsonWallet = fs.readFileSync('<<path to UTC file>>');
const parsedWallet = JSON.parse(jsonWallet);
const wallet = EthereumWallet.fromV3(parsedWallet, '<<YOUR_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE>>');`

Comment: @Ismael I tried this way too but it is bad approach because I have to keep wallet locally (in my case- in Git tree).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, finally I added some code to unlock account on the fly. I do not want to store password in `truffle.js` (but it is possible), so doing next things:

Changed `1_initial_migration.js` this way:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const TruffleConfig = require('../truffle');

var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");


module.exports = function(deployer, network, addresses) {
  const config = TruffleConfig.networks[network];

  if (process.env.ACCOUNT_PASSWORD) {
    const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://' + config.host + ':' + config.port));

    console.log('>> Unlocking account ' + config.from);
    web3.personal.unlockAccount(config.from, process.env.ACCOUNT_PASSWORD, 36000);
  }

  console.log('>> Deploying migration');
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

And instead of calling `truffle deploy` I am running it like:

```
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD=MySup4P@ssw0rd truffle deploy
```

As you can see node url and port are taken from config, so it is possible to add `password` fields there, then check in migration for "callability" i.e.:

```
...
password: function() { return process.env.ACCOUNT_PASSWORD }
...
```

-- same thing but password logic will be moved to `truffle.js`

Comment: You do not want to store the password in truffle.js, but are fine with having it in your environment and console command history?

Comment: Works, but it needs to be `web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount` as of web3 1.0.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when deploying to a quorum chain. Receiving `abort(Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "")` alongside with a 630kb error output. Any updates on that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this for dev purposes, there could be another way which is to have a script which unlocks the accounts periodically. The advantage of this method is that the migration scripts need not be updated.

An example of this can be found in the [trufflesuite/truffle geth-accounts.js](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/develop/scripts/geth-accounts.js). Although the method above is still highly inefficient, since it tries to unlock accounts in an infinite loop. A slightly remodified version looks like this

```js
 function unlockAccounts () {
  eth.accounts.forEach(function (account) {
    console.log('Unlocking ' + account + '.');
    personal.unlockAccount(account, '', 86400);
  });
}


function createAccounts() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    acc = personal.newAccount("");
    eth.sendTransaction({
      from: eth.accounts[0], 
      to: acc, 
      value: web3.toWei(100, "ether")
    });
  }
  unlockAccounts();
  setInterval(unlockAccounts, 86000);
}

createAccounts();
```