# Deploy from Remix to Quorum using password? "authentication needed: password or unlock"

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, accounts, quorum

I can SSH into the box that is running Quorum:

1. run `geth` with the flag `--allow-insecure-unlock`
2. `geth attach new-node-1/geth.ipc`
3. `personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])`

I'm interested in knowing if I can use the password directly from Remix?

[image]

*(I'm also running a virtual desktop on my box, that's why `localhost:22000` works for me)*

#### But why?

I had some troubles with network configuration and temporarily my AWS security policy is "wide open", all the ports accessible by the public.

I'm worried that if I do `unlockAccount` someone could mess with my stuff.

For the production environment majority of the ports will be closed but for the sake of learning I would like to know is there a way to use a password directly from the UI?

---

A little bit related: [Truffle mingration: Error: authentication needed: password or unlock](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25413/truffle-mingration-error-authentication-needed-password-or-unlock) - interactive command prompt in Truffle script.

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way to unlock from the Remix UI in either the Quorum plugin or regular Remix. But it would probably be a good feature to add to the plugin.

The alternative right now is to temporarily unlock it and deploy (you can pass a second parameter to unlockAccount to tell it exactly how long to keep unlocked). You can also go to the compilation details, copy the WEB3DEPLOY code, and use that directly in the geth console instead. You would need to add calls to unlock and lock before and after sending like in the Truffle question you linked.